# How to change the Terminal in Android Studio to iTerm2?

Tags: android, android-studio

As the title says, is there any way to change the default Terminal of Android Studio to iTerm2 on Mac OS?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144180297

Answer (score 31):

I haven't tested it on a Mac, but at least on Windows you can select the shell used by the Terminal window in the Settings Menu (for example from the default cmd.exe to TCC/LE).

I suspect it should be the same way,

**`File -> Settings -> Terminal -> Shell path`**

See the [IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html#d1070267e107) for the Terminal plugin.

Comment: I can change `bash` to `zsh` in this way, but can't change the terminal application, thx all the same

Comment: @Jerome Sorry, thought iTerm was a shell. I'm not a Mac user, as you can see. :/

Comment: @matiash I iTerm is a terminal application and your steps is for changing the shell path which is different. If you could delete this answer then it would be less confusing as it doesn't answer the original question at all

Answer (score 8):

For Mac OS

**File -> Other Settings -> Preference for New Projects -> Shell path**

Windows OS

Please follow @matiash answer.

**Alternative**

It will work both on Terminal and in Android Studio.

- To check available shells: available shells run:  **cat /etc/shells**
- To select your favourite (I am selecting bash): **chsh -s /bin/bash**

That's all.

Comment: Thank you.
It worked on the Mac terminal. 
But in Android Studio's Terminal it didn't work!

Comment: Hi @Waheed, your steps are for changing the shell script while OP wanted to change the terminal application to the iTerm application. Have you also tried this yourself before posting this answer :( If yes it could have avoided lots of confusion

Answer (score 2):

Do it on Mac:

go to **File/Other Settings/Preferences For New Projects**
then in **Terminal** tab, change the **"Shell Path"** attribute. 
You may click on the folder icon on the right side of this field and choose your desired shell.